# Launch my app once NFC tag is detected, then display result

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc

I've made an application who can read a NFC tag and display his content (once he has been parsed) following this tutorial : https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-nfc-reader-application-for-android-74cf24f38a6f except that I had a button who needs to be pushed if you want to scan a NFC tag.

Now, in my AndroidManifest.xml I added an intent filter to allow my app to start if a NFG tag is detected from my device :

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.example" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

It launchs my app but nothing happens. I means, i have no result about the NFC tag... 
How to get tag's content while my app is opening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the information from the Intent that started the Ativity.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc

> If an activity starts because of an NFC intent, you can obtain information about the scanned NFC tag from the intent. Intents can contain the following extras depending on the tag that was scanned:

```
EXTRA_TAG (required): A Tag object representing the scanned tag.
EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES (optional): An array of NDEF messages parsed from the tag. This extra is mandatory on ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED intents.
EXTRA_ID (optional): The low-level ID of the tag.
```

so:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    ...
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == intent.action) {
        intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)?.also { rawMessages ->
            val messages: List<NdefMessage> = rawMessages.map { it as NdefMessage }
            // Process the messages array.
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
val tag: Tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! That's really helpful and interesting

Comment: Sure but finally I have a problem ahah ! I just put a Log.d in "onNewIntent" and he doesn't display when the application starts when a scan is detected.

Comment: You can also try `onCreate` or on `onResume` with `getIntent`

Comment: Thanks ! 
Just a last question : Why does my function onResume is called just after onCreate ? It doesn't make sense, right ?

Comment: It's the activity lifecycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle  the Activity goes through onCreate > onResume > onStart > "User Interactions" > onStop > onPause > onDestroy.